# azure logic app: Write data to a local excel file

Tags: azure-logic-apps

We have options to write data to Excel Online (Business and OneDrive).
But i need to write data to a local excel file in my system. I didnt find any connector for the same. Any workarounds please?

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, you could accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the [`File System connector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-using-file-connector) and Azure Logic Apps, you can create automated tasks and workflows that create and manage files **on an on-premises file share**.

Before you can connect logic apps to on-premises systems such as your file system server, you need to install and [set up an on-premises data gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install). That way, you can specify to use your gateway installation when you create the file system connection from your logic app.

Configure the connector to on premise path and you could go on.

[image]